# ¿como evitar salir de un entry a otro si la validación no se cumple y el campo no es vacío?

Tags: python

Tengo un ingreso de los horarios de entrada y salida del personal (se invoca desde el Boton "Tiempo Total", funcion tt() ) . Cada campo debe indicar hora y minutos en formato "00:00". Con la función valida lo realiza bien pero lo que quiero evitar es que salga del Entry hasta que la validación se cumpla y el Entry no este vacío.
Soy nuevo en Phyton. He trabajado en Excel programando rutinas en visual Basic y me esta costando adaptarme.
Una opcion que trate pero nopude saber como es anular todos los eventos del Entry y solo que utilizar cuando presionar Enter o Tab pero no tube exito
Desde ya Muchas Gracias.

```
    def valida(new_text):
    
        while new_text!="":
            """
            Chequear que `new_text` esté en formato dd/mm/aaaa.
            """
    
            if len(new_text) > 5 :
                return False
            checks = []
            for i, char in enumerate(new_text):
                # En los índices 2 y 5 deben estar los caracteres "/".
    
                if i in (2,2):
                    checks.append(char == ":")
                else:
                    # En el resto de los casos, la única restricción es que sean
                    # números entre el 0 y el 9.
                    checks.append(char.isdecimal())
            # `all()` retorna verdadero si todos los chequeos son verdaderos.
            return all(checks)
    
    def tt():
        tt_e = LabelFrame(root, text="Tiempo del Proyecto", width=350, height=270, relief="groove", borderwidth=5, bg="green", fg="white")
        tt_e.place(x=630, y=10)
    
        tit1 = Label(tt_e, text="Mañana                  Tarde ", width=20, bg="green", fg="white", anchor="w").place(x=90, y=5)
        tit = Label(tt_e,  text="Entrada  Salida         Entrada  Salida", width=30, bg="green", fg="white", anchor="w").place(x=70, y=28)

        eml1=StringVar()
        eml = Entry(tt_e, width=5, textvariable=eml1, validate="key",
        validatecommand=(root.register(valida), "%P"))
        eml.place(x=76, y=51)
        eml.focus_set()
        sml = Entry(tt_e, width=5, validate="key", validatecommand=(root.register(valida), "%P")).place(x=119, y=51)
        etl = Entry(tt_e, width=5, validate="key", validatecommand=(root.register(valida), "%P"))
        etl.place(x=180, y=51)
        sml = Entry(tt_e, width=5, validate="key",
        validatecommand=(root.register(valida), "%P")).place(x=220, y=51)
               
    
    
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Imagen del proyecto]

El código esta recortado y muestra solo la función y una parte de los Entry ultilizados